# making image url dynamic

Tags: apex, visualforce

kindly help me how pass the id from the static resource as a dynamic value in the below code:-
visualforce:-

```
<apex:repeat value="{!accs}" var="a">
    <img src="/resource/1505214096000/flaf" alt="flag" style="height:30px; width:150px;" border="0"/>
    <apex:outputText value="{!a.name}"/><br/>
</apex:repeat>
```

here i want '1505214096000' to be passed as a dynamic value.
apex:-

```
List<staticresource> srlst=[select id,name from staticresource];
```

Comment: check this https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gx7nAAA

Comment: or use `<apex:image value="{!$Resource[customLogo]}"/>`

Comment: The number is not necessary; you can simply say "/resource/resourcename" if you prefer. You can also literally use any random number if you want to avoid cache hits.

Answer (score 0):

<apex:variable var="imagenURL"
value="{!custom_Obj.campo}"
/>

```
  <apex:image id="imagenfirma"
    value="{!URLFOR($Resource[imagenURL])}"
    width="140"
    height="140"
    alt="Description of image here"
  />
```